# Python: Defining a tuple with unknown values inbetween

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, ipython

This is a most interesting thing in python I've come across in variable referencing as tuple.
Could someone give me an equivalent in C???

```
h = 1,_,3,_

h
Out[2]: (1, '', 3, '')

 h = 1,'',3, ''

h
Out[5]: (1, '', 3, '')
```

How does this happen? 
Is _ and '' equal? What is the difference?

how many such magical referencing are possible i wonder??

Answer (score 3):

The default value of `_` in IPython shell is `''`:

```
monty@xonix:~/py$ ipython --classic
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:32:33) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
>>> _
''
>>> 2*2
4
>>> _  # Now _ returns the value of last expression
4
```

Comment: in shell, python gives NameError where '_' is not defined. So using '' is a better practice? WHich means its an ipython convention and we should generally denote empty string with ''

Comment: @user2290820 yes in normal shell, it is not defined until you do some calculations.